# How to "nullify" a search box (so it doesn't trigger an accordion)

Tags: html, css

I have an accordion menu.

Inside the top bar of the page (inside the link that opens the accordion), I have a link to the front page which doesn't open the accordion:

```
<span data-href="homepage.com" onclick="document.location.href = this.getAttribute('data-href'); return false;"> 
   <img src="image.png">
</span>
```

The rest of the top bar triggers the accordion, which is what I want.

However, I want to add a search box on the top bar also. Problem is, when I click the search field to enter text, it triggers the accordion, so I can't enter text.

How can I modify the above link code to make the search box work?

```
<div class="searchbox">
   <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
      <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"></label>
         <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search">
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="&#128269">
   </form>
</div>
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the field is not disabled and you're still able to enter text in, you could try this:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

I haven't tested it (and certainly not in an accordion), but we use it in some of our code to prevent events.

Comment: I tried it in the div parent of the search field as well as in a span wrapped around the search field. Still triggers the accordion. Thanks anyway